# combine both these queries and return the one that match the most

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I have ***$table*** which 'is_contain' field is either 1 or 0. I have several Obj records that have 'active' and 'is_contain' fields.

**First scenario:**

> $table->is_contain=1
>
> Obj records available:
>
> - 'id'=1 'active'=1 and 'is_contain'=0
> - 'id'=2 'active'=1 and 'is_contain'=1
>
> should return Obj record which id=2

**Second scenario:**

> $table->is_contain=1
>
> Obj records available:
>
> - 'id'=1 'active'=1 and 'is_contain'=0
>
> should return Obj record which id=1

If **$table->is_contain=1** and has Obj record which 'is_contain'=1, then return this particular Obj record which 'is_contain'=1 otherwise return record which 'is_contain'=0

At first I used ->get() like below instead of ->first() but ->get() will return all the two Obj records which is not what I want as I have to traverse these two records and get the one with 'is_contain'=1.

```
$obj=Obj::whereActive(1)->where(function($query)use($table){
    if($table->is_contain){
        $query->where('is_contain',1)->orWhere('is_contain',0);
    }
})
->get();
```

Now I separated into two because if use ->first(), it will always return the first collection which sometimes like this example, Obj record 'is_contain' field is not 1.

```
$obj=Obj::whereActive(1)->where(function($query)use($table){
    if($table->is_contain){
        $query->where('is_contain',1);
    }
})
->first();

if($obj==null&&$table->is_contain){
    $obj=Obj::whereActive(1)->first();
}
```

Is there any way to combine these two queries into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just order by `is_contain` field descreasly, and take the first row:

```php
$obj = Obj::whereActive(1);
if ($table->is_contain) {
    $obj = $obj->orderBy('is_contain', 'DESC')->first();
}
```

Comment: is_contain field is of boolean, orderBy doesnt work on it

Comment: @unknown r u using mysql as driver?

Comment: @unknown MySQL does not have built-in Boolean type. However, it uses TINYINT(1) instead. So it is still integer.

Comment: im using sequel pro to access my database. and yes, is_contain is of TINYINT